# How can I bring back the original version of a file in git? Even though I have commited the file and had been pushed?

Tags: git

I have a file and I modified it then commited and pushed. How can I retrieve its org version in GIT? What should I do cause I want its original version back.

Comment: `git checkout {revision} -- {filename}`

Comment: What value should I put inside {}?

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing your commit log with:

```
git log
```

Then, you can revert to a specific commit by copying the SHA, the long string of alphanumeric characters, and entering it in the command.

```
git revert <insert SHA here>
```

For more information, check out the docs at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert.

**EDIT:** Note that this will reset your HEAD to the old commit. If you want to just peek at an older version, use checkout as suggested in the comments.